# How to disable "..." expansion in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched from Bash to zsh and I realise I now have troubles using bazel tool: in lots of cases I run commands in the current directory invoking `bazel run ...` or `bazel query ...`.

Unfortunately, those three dots are expanded to `../..` which doesn't make any sense for me:

```
$ echo ...
../..
```

I found I can quote those dots and do `bazel run '...'`, but I wonder is there a way to disable this expansion completely - I never use this three-dots-short-cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...` alias is defined by [Oh-My-Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/40ff950fcd081078a8cd3de0eaab784f85c681d5/lib/directories.zsh#L8C1-L8C9), a third-party collection of configuration files for `zsh`.

We can [unalias](https://www.linfo.org/unalias.html) the command by adding the following:

```
unalias \...
```

inside the `~/.zshrc` file, this needs to be done after the line that sources the `om-my-zsh.sh` script

Comment: Right! I suspected it is an alias, but I checked it through `alias ...` which apparently also was expanded :-). Thanks!

Comment: `...` is a global alias, since it's meant to be used with `cd`, so it's expanded in all positions, not just command position.